# Link segments matched by column value in R

Tags: r, plot, matching, lines

Hello

I am attempting to plot segmented lines and connect them by matching values.

I have already plotted segments by the "Start" and "End" values as x coordinates and the Group as the y coordinates in R. I would like to connect these segments with a line if they share the same "id", as indicated by my sample dataset *data*:

```
Name  Start   End      Group   ID

TP1   363248  366670   7       98

TP2   365869  369291   11      98

TP3   366459  369881   1       98

AB1   478324  481599   11      134

AB2   478855  482130   1       134

AB3   480681  483956   10      134

JD1   166771  169764   6       214

JD2   386419  389244   7       214

JD2   389025  391850   11      214
```

What I have so far using *data* is:

```
x <- seq(0, 4100000, length = 200)
y <- seq(0, 15, length = 200)
plot(x,y,type="n");

start.x <- (data[,2])
end.x   <- (data[,3])
end.y   <- start.y <- (data[,4]) # from and to y coords the same

segments(x0 = start.x, y0 = start.y, x1 = end.x, y1 = end.y)

lines(data[,1], data[,5])
```

My segments are plotted just fine, but my connecting lines do not appear. Any suggestions as to how I can draw connecting lines? Thank you very much.

Comment: Is it intentional that your plot is extremely "zoomed out"? Your segments appear as tiny dots on the far left side.

Comment: Also, do you want to draw connecting lines between *all* pairs of segments that share an `ID`? Or just pairs that occur consecutively within the data.frame?

Comment: The data I provided is just a sample from a large data set, but yes I'm looking to connect lines between all pairs of segments that share an ID. Some segments that share IDs are very distant from each other within the data.frame. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my code below I zoomed in the plot using the `xlim` and `ylim` parameters so we can get a better look at the plotted data.

As you can see, I'm using a `for` loop to iterate over each unique `ID` value. For each value, I get the combinations of all pairs of records in the group using `combn()`. I then iterate over each combination using `apply()`. For each combination I call `segments()` to draw a segment between the centers of the two (original) segments. I use a different color for each group so they can easily be distinguished.

```
df <- data.frame(Name=c('TP1','TP2','TP3','AB1','AB2','AB3','JD1','JD2','JD2'),Start=c(363248,365869,366459,478324,478855,480681,166771,386419,389025),End=c(366670,369291,369881,481599,482130,483956,169764,389244,391850),Group=c(7,11,1,11,1,10,6,7,11),ID=c(98,98,98,134,134,134,214,214,214));
xlim <- c(min(df$Start),max(df$End));
ylim <- c(min(df$Group),max(df$Group));
plot(NA,xlim=xlim,ylim=ylim,xlab='x',ylab='y');
start.x <- df[,'Start'];
end.x <- df[,'End'];
end.y <- start.y <- df[,'Group'];
segments(start.x,start.y,end.x,end.y);
uid <- unique(df$ID);
cols <- rainbow(length(uid));
for (i in seq_along(uid)) {
    df.sub <- subset(df,ID==uid[i]);
    col <- cols[i];
    apply(combn(nrow(df.sub),2),2,function(ris) {
        r1 <- df.sub[ris[1],];
        r2 <- df.sub[ris[2],];
        segments(mean(c(r1$Start,r1$End)),r1$Group,mean(c(r2$Start,r2$End)),r2$Group,col=col);
    });
};
```

[image: plot]